# Способы автоформатирования текста, введенного в EditText в Kotlin Android

Tags: android, android-edittext, bigdecimal, маска

Мне нужно, чтобы, когда я вводил денежные суммы, то текст сразу бы форматировался в нужный мне денежный формат. Например, ввел 1000 - в editText сразу текст отображался бы как 1 000; 10000 -> 10 000; 100000 -> 100 000. При этом можно вводить не только целые значения, т.е. пользователь может ввести 10003.034 и в этом случае число должно отобразиться как 10 003,034. Локали 2: En/Rus. Есть ли относительно простой способ сделать такое? Или нужно с нуля свое кастомное вью с логикой писать? Уже много разных решений испробовал, но как правило все заканчивается крашами приложения после первого форматирования или попытке стереть текст, либо поддерживается ввод лишь целых чисел)

```
    editText.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
        var current = ""
            override fun afterTextChanged(salary: Editable?) {

                /* формат */
                if (salary.toString() != current) {
                    editText.removeTextChangedListener(this)
                    val formatter = DecimalFormat()
                    val symbols = DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance()
                    symbols.groupingSeparator = ' '
                    formatter.decimalFormatSymbols = symbols
                    val newValue = formatter.format(salary.toString().toBigDecimal()).toString()
                    current = newValue
                    editText.setText(newValue)
                    editText.setSelection(newValue.length)
                    editText.addTextChangedListener(this)
                }


            }

            override fun beforeTextChanged(salary: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {
            }
            override fun onTextChanged(salary: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
            }
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

Ваш код неверен в том, что меняет текст напрямую в контроле и из-за этого вынужден переподписываться. Все проще.

Вот рабочий код для целых сумм с лимитом на разрядность для локали ru-RU.
Лимит можно убрать и переделать для десятичных и нескольких локалей.

```
class AmountTextWatcher(val limit: Int) : TextWatcher {
    private val formatter = NumberFormat.getIntegerInstance(Locale.forLanguageTag("ru-RU"))
    val delimiter = formatter.format(1000)[1].toString()
    override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {
    }
    override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
    }
    override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable) {
        if (s.isNotBlank()) {
            val num = try { formatter.parse(s.toString().take(limit)) } catch (ex: ParseException) { null }
            val numStr = num?.let { formatter.format(num) } ?: ""
            if (s.toString() != numStr) {
                s.replace(0, s.length, numStr)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Я может не до конца понимаю смысл работы этого кода, но здесь точно код рабочий, хотя бы для целых чисел? Просто даже разделитель (delimiter) нигде не используется. У меня крашится приложение на той позиции, где ставлю лимит. Или может быть я неправильно использую это все

Comment: Вешаю на editText   editText.addTextChangedListener(object : AmountTextWatcher(5){}). Точнее ловлю краш не на той позиции даже где limit, а после ввода четырех символов

Comment: А зачем вы готовый к употреблению класс через object переопределяете? https://kotlinlang.org/docs/object-declarations.html#object-expressions

Comment: Вам достаточно в этом коде достаточно понять главное, что при работе с TextWatcher нет необходимости напрямую обращаться к EditText, тот обьект Editable что вам передается в метод afterTextChanged(...) дает вам полный доступ к редактируемому тексту.